# Laravel - Method link_to_action does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 5.8.32. I used in my blade view:

```
{{ HTML::link_to_action('HomeController@index') }}
```

But it shows : **Method link_to_action does not exist.**

So why does it produce the error ? How to solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

The `HTML` helpers has been deprecated in Laravel 5.0.

In **Laravel 5.8**, you can generate a URL to a given controller action with:

```
$url = action([HomeController::class, 'index'], ['param' => 'value']);
```

Since `action` is a global helper, you can use it in a view easily:

```
{{ action([HomeController::class, 'index']) }}
```

Comment: how can I use it in view ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how it can be used in a view